# fcntl: Turning disk buffering on and off

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have written a short C program to turn unix file buffering on and off.  The code below is to turn it on.  I use fcntl to get the settings, set the O_SYNC flag, then write the settings back to ther kernel.  But when i get the settings again, they O_SYNC flag is not set.

```
int result, s;
s = fcntl(*fd, F_GETFL);
s |= O_SYNC; // set SYNC bit
result = fcntl(*fd, F_SETFL, s);

if( result == -1 )
   perror("setting SYNC");
else
{
    // Check buffering is on
    s = fcntl(*fd, F_GETFL); //
    if((s & O_SYNC) == O_SYNC) // check if SYNC bit is set
        printf("In function buffering_off(): Buffering is OFF\n");
    else
        printf("In function buffering_off(): Buffering is ON\n");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers :)

Comment: You should also check out your kernel version, http://milek.blogspot.de/2010/12/linux-osync-and-write-barriers.html says that this feature was introduced in 2.6.31 only.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this discussion on the Linux Kernel list: http://choon.net/forum/read.php?21,22539

In a nutshell:

> The problem is that `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags|O_SYNC)` appears to work, but silently ignores the `O_SYNC` flag. 
>   Opening the file with `O_SYNC` works okay, but setting it later on via `fcntl` doesn't work.

It sounds like this bug was there since day one, but may have been fixed recently (I am not sure of the current status as far as shipping kernels are concerned).

> I am using SuSE Linux, a version that is about 6 years old.

The discussion is from about a year ago. Given the age of your kernel, it's definitely affected by the bug.

Comment: I am using SuSE Linux, a version that is about 6 years old.  Maybe it is a bug in Linux OSs as opposed to UNIX.

Comment: @Kiyomasa: That discussion is specifically about Linux, and the thread is about one year old. Therefore your kernel is definitely affected by the bug.